# Set default value of ListPreference

Tags: android

How I can set the default value of the ListPreference?

For the EditTextPreference i used

```
editor.putString("name","defaultvalue");
```

but this doesn't work in ListPreference.

How i can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it from xml:

```
android:defaultValue
```

or:

```
onSetInitialValue(boolean restoreValue, Object defaultValue)
// Implement this to set the initial value of the Preference.
```

Comment: In XML defaultValue does not worok.